# destroy dependent data without destroying original record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an easy way to destroy data associated with a particular record, without destroying the original record.  For example, if I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: pets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many: houses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If I wanted to delete a user and all their pets and houses, I could just do something like:

```
user = User.first
user.destroy
```

But what if I want to keep the user, but just want to delete their pets and houses?  Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: On what event you want to destroy associated records?

Comment: `User.pets.delete_all` and `User.houses.delete_all`

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia

Comment: It's not on a particular event.  I just want to be able to call an instance method like `house.destroy_dependent_pets`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually, with a callback for example.

```
class User

   {callback} :destroy_pets

   private

   def destroy_pets
     self.pets.delete_all   
   end
 end
```

Comment: if I do `self.pets.delete_all` that won't call the `destroy` method for the associated pets, correct?  So if they had dependent objects, it wouldn't destroy those.